# Sinatra App Routes Not Working As Anticipated

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I've been doing a Ruby course on Skillcrush (still very much an amateur) and have come across a part of the course where my code just doesn't work.

The app uses Sinatra, and is supposed to show the `views/people/index.erb` when going to `localhost:9292/people`, but instead it goes to the error page which it should when the wrong extension is given after `localhost:9292/` (normally a date format, but if anything else is entered it should bring an error).

I had to switch computers half way through the course, so have a feeling it may be to do with my setup. I've used the code that they've supplied and have checked for discrepancies using `diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/` and can only see some in my `Gemfile.lock` file. I'm using Ruby 2.4 due to issues with gems on pre-2.0 Ruby and wondered if this might be the case?

My code can be seen [here](https://github.com/davemate23/sinatra-mvc).

Can anyone see any glaring issues?

Comment: Please post your code here. You only have a readme file pushed

Comment: by default in sinatra, the folder is `views` but you have `view`

Comment: I've now uploaded the rest of the code. @maxple apologies that was a typo.

Comment: @DaveC it's unlikely that people will be willing to go through the code in your Github repo, scanning the whole thing for errors. Anyway, the most important thing is the error itself, which you should paste here as text

Comment: The error is that it posts the **Oops! You should enter a valid birthdate in the form of mmddyyyy. Try again!** in `index_controller.rb` when going to `localhost:9292/people` as mentioned. There are no actual errors in the terminal. I was wondering if it was something that had changed in ruby or associated gems, otherwise it doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what is happening is that Sinatra is pattern matching your url `localhost:9292/people` to the first route of your index controller `get '/:birthdate'` instead of `get '/people'`. Sinatra takes the request and then checks each of the routes in order, the first one to match then handles the request.

To test this:

- try changing `get '/:birthdate'` to `get '/birthdate/:birthdate'` (if it works you would then have to change any links to birthdate appropriately).

or

- comment out the birthdate route

or

- move all the routes into the same file and change the order they are arranged in to get a feel for how the pattern matching is occurring.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I'm following a course and it seems to have worked for everyone else? I'm a little concerned that if I change my code then I'll lose track of the course.

Comment: I'm just curious if you tried one of my suggestions to see if that was the cause of the error (the second one would be the place I would start). Also, the first suggestion is a pretty benign change, I don't think it would trip you up much going forward. Basically if the course asks you to link to `/<%= #{birthdate} %>` you just have to change it to `/birthdate/<%= #{birthdate} %>`

Comment: It does work through doing that, which is what I assumed. It obviously then doesn't allow a user to input their date of birth straight after the domain then though as intended. Just bizarre why it's not working when nobody else on course seems to have had the same issue.

Comment: Is it possible when you switched computers that the order of the controller files changed?

Comment: How would they be arranged? By date?